# Armature Mesh Deformation

Tags: mesh, armature, parent, pose-mode

Ever since I symmetrized the mesh so that it was perfectly symmetrical, the armature started deforming whenever I rotated it.

[image]

This was a completely new armature I made from scratch, I can't tell if it's the armature or the mesh that's making this awful deformation.  What is happening?  I put the automatic weights setting.

Also, when I rotated the armature on its own, it stretches the bones.  When I rotate just one bone it stretches only the tips of the fingers, and then mirrors the effect on the opposite side.  How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Going by the image alone,  it seems like the nails might be the problem. I have seen figures with separate nail meshes and that causes problems with AW.

*-snip-*

One bit of unrelated advice, if this model is to be used in Blender, renaming your bones and adding .L and .R (left and right) at the end will greatly speed up your work. "Forearm.R" reads a lot faster than "Bone 50" and allows you acess to built-in functions like *Paste Mirrored Pose*

**Edit**

The next item on your checklist is to go into **Weight Paint Mode** and check if the messed up parts are (somehow) assigned to another bone.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I removed the armature modifier and all the vertex groups, and I made sure that the nails were not separate objects.  Unfortunately ever since I deleted the vertex groups now whenever I parent the mesh to the bones and click the automatic weights setting it doesn't move the mesh at all!  There must be something wrong with the mesh as a whole, the armature refuses to apply weights to it.  It all happened after I symmetrized it.

Comment: Make sure that both mesh and armature are in *Object Mode* when you parent.

Comment: Forgot to ask; when you used *Symmetrize* did you select all the mesh?

Comment: Yeah, I clicked the A key to select all the mesh.

Comment: It seems like I just can't symmetrize the arms. I symmetrized the head only and nothing went wrong.  But whenever I symmetrized the arms and moved the armature the bone also moves the opposite side of the mesh in the opposite direction.  It's like it also symmetrizes the weight the armature has on the mesh.  It's never done that to me before, and even when I made a completely new armature it has the same effect.  So it has to be the mesh.

Comment: Try using *Snap to Symmetry* on just one side of the mesh